# CSS Grid Systems: Purpose of positive padding simultaneously with negative margin?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

Grid Systems use code like (or similar) this snippet:

```
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 1170px;
}

.row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Setting a left-, right-padding I can understand. It prevents the content from touching the viewport-edges when the viewport becomes smaller.

But in the next this is becomes practically removed by applying a negative margin to the child-element (.row).

That doesn't make sense to me.

**What's the purpose of this pattern?**

Comment: Is using the `row` class optional? I could see it as a useful pattern to "pull out" a specific section of content whilst other child elements respect the `container`'s padding.

Comment: Yep. Optional. It's just recommended to put the further child elements into a div with class "row". I guess you are right. That makes sense. Thanks a lot.